# How do I configure bridges to re-connect if the other end disconnects?

Tags: mqtt

I have three brokers: one central and two outliers. The central broker is set to persist messages and has bridge connections with QoS 2 to the two outlying brokers.

However, I am finding that if one of the outliers goes offline for some reason and the bridge breaks, the central broker does not attempt to re-establish the broken bridge.

An example of the bridge connection config:

```
connection <redacted>
address <redacted>
remote_username <redacted>
remote_password <redacted>
topic # out 2
topic # in 2
```